# Как скрыть id поста в htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /viewpost.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

**site.com/viewpost.php?id=593?title=title_of_page**

Мне нужно получить url такого вида `site.com/title_of_page`.

Мне удалось скрыть `viewpost.php?id=`.

Cейчас адрес выглядит так `site.com/593?title=title_of_page`

Как скрыть `593?title=`?
Можно ли так делать?

Comment: очевидно, если раньше пост показывался по id, а вы хотите его убрать, то логику кода, ответственного за показ поста придется переписать, чтобы поиск был по названию.

Comment: Также учтите, что если названия постов будут одинаковыми, то вам придётся решать и этот вопрос.